# initialize fortran character array with variable length strings

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a code where I set up a character array with set of default "options", which I may or may not wish to overwrite during the code execution.  If I initialize the array with strings of all the same length (shorter or equal to the maximum possible length of 5), then the code works:

```
PROGRAM test
  character(len=5) :: s(3)=["a","b","c"]
  s(1)="12345678"
  print *,s
END PROGRAM test
```

output

```
12345b    c
```

But if the strings are variable lengths.

```
character(len=5) :: s(3)=["a","bb","c"]
```

Then I get a compilation error:

```
Error: Different CHARACTER lengths (1/2) in array constructor at (1)
```

I can get it to work by padding with spaces to make all string equal like this

```
 character(len=5) :: s(3)=["a ","bb","c "]
```

But that is a bit tedious for my actual example as I have some very long strings, so it is a lot of space-bar-pressing-while-counting-out-loud...  Is there a way to inititalize character arrays with variable length variables, i.e. some kind of auto padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually specify the [type-spec](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-types-constants-and-variables/variables-1/arrays/array-constructors.html) in the array constructor, as

```
character(len=5) :: s(3) = [character(len=5) :: "a", "bb", "c"]
```

this will convert each element in the array to same type, `character(len=5)`, such that the array constructor is legal.

Comment: Not sure, language lawyers are you allowed `Character(len=Len(s))` in the array constructor? That would avoid having to specify the length twice.

Comment: @IanBush, if you want a more detailed answer than "yes", that sounds like a proper Question.